# Are there any guidelines for the usage of namespace in big projects?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces

Are there any commonly accepted guidelines for usage and organization of namespaces in big projects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[MIcrosoft's guidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/893ke618.aspx) is `CompanyName.TechnologyName[.Feature][.Design]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try FxCop, there are some rules.

1. Generally you can make some base prefix (company)
2. Then add the tiers/modules of the project (DAL, UI, Common, etc)

Then I add folder names to the namespace.

So if my file with MegaUtil class is in prj Common in folder Utils/Misc it will be:

```
YourCompanyName.Common.Utils.Misc
```

Comment: Folders and namespaces shouldn't be confused or combined.  In larger projects there might be significant differences between the two hierarchies!

Comment: This is general guideline for Java projects - combining folders and namespaces. I know it's not in Microsoft guidelines, but it's rather logical. If you are working with folders and it's up to you - you can build hierarchy as you want. That works for me very well.

Comment: "Folders and namespaces shouldn't be confused or combined." - I disagree with this.  In general it's a good idea to create a Folder hierarchy that matches the namespace hierarchy.  For one thing, Visual Studio uses the folder hierarchy as the namespace when adding classes to a folder.

Comment: @Joe - totally agree. And resharper helps such tasks greatly. And also it helps navigation :)

Comment: If you have significant difference between folder and namespace hierarchies in a large scale project - somebody needs to be taken out back and flogged

Comment: What about Silverlight and WPF? where do they fit? for instance I could have
company.WPF.Common? or is it Company.Common.WPF where I would have to compile seperately for silverlight and wpf? That is my primary issue right now; Before I started using silverlight I had a CompanyName.Core class...but now I have to have a Company.Silverlight.Core that has a lot of duplicate functionality but is compiled against silverlight instead of 4.0

Comment: Yeah, that can be acceptable. You can add wpf and silverlight as keys. Just follow it everywhere. And remember about shared files functionality when building projects against different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces are mainly just about avoiding Ambiguity with other classes/Objects. And in terms of organization I like to organize UI elements away from other working Function;

tip:
To make sure your code is never confused with other objects use a reverse order of a domain name that may be registered for the product.

```
com.somecompany.app.*


    com.somecompany.Math;   
                     Math.work(a,b)

    com.somecompany.UI;
                     UI.SomeUserControl
                     UI.AnotherUserControl
                     UI.Forms;


    com.somecompany.Web;
```

Comment: Ew, the `com` prefix is horrible!

Comment: Why did you start with `com`?

Comment: something I saw I saw a few years back, its manly to avoid Ambiguity so using a reverse domain name.
Its not vital, can drop the com. or net. and use another prefix such as lib. (for library).
Im not attatched to it, its mainly to seperate my code from others.

Comment: I don't understand. Doesn't the `somecompany` part already separate your code from others? What's the point of adding a reverse domain name?

Comment: Like I said, its not Vital, the Microsoft standard works fine and can be descriptive about its classes if organized right. Its just a technique I picked up from some book before .NET days.

Comment: This might be a good idea for XML namespaces - not sure about C# ;)

Comment: I don't like your casing either. Pascal casing is pretty standard for namespaces/classes/methods.

Comment: The [reverse domain notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_domain_name_notation) is the thing you are suggesting. It is adopted as a standard naming convensions for Java-based and Apple software, but is not the standard way to organize components in the .NET world. Both the official .NET assemblies, the Mono project and nearly the entire .NET dev community have agreed to conform to the Pascal Case standard. There is no restriction, nor it is a crime, to use reverse domain names in .NET, but your project's components will seem awkward to use by the community who are used to the standard

Answer (score 0):

..

E.g. if your companys name is Sample Software Solutions and you were writing an ATM system then you might have assemblies like:

- SSS.ATM.Domain
- SSS.ATM.Data
- SSS.ATM.Common(an assembly common across ATM)
- SSS.ATM.Services
- SSS.ATM.UI SSS.Common (an assembly common across all products)

We would then typically have some unit test assemblies:

- SSS.ATM.Domain.UT
- SSS.ATM.Data.UT
- SSS.ATM.Common.UT
- SSS.ATM.Services.UT
- SSS.ATM.UI.UT
- SSS.Common.UT

And there may also be one or two IT or AT assemblies (Integration / Acceptance testing) e.g.

- SSS.ATM.Domain.IT (Integration testing the domain)
- SSS.ATM.UI.AT (Acceptence testing through UI)

Comment: Not a huge fan of all the abbrevs.

Comment: Its simple to get used of it. It works really well for us to be honest. Plus, with well known abbreviations in namespaces, you end up conveying alot of information about a class while not muddling the code too much with very long namespaces.

Comment: Unless you know about `using` directives. Then you can have descriptive identifiers *and* un-cluttered code.

Comment: In these examples I would use Sss.Atm... to match Microsoft's casing guidelines. ATM and UI are well-known acronyms so the abbreviation is appropriate, however I would use UnitTests rather than UT for the unit test assemblies.  But consistency with your team's standards is more important than strictly adhering to the Microsoft guidelines.

Comment: But why waste time creating/maintaining your own standards when you can take Microsoft's straight off the shelf?

Comment: In my experience namespace standards are completely subjective. In one company you could be adhering to Microsoft whereas another could use their own standards. There is no right and wrong way - its what works for that matters. @ShellShock Many people simply dont like Microsoft standards!

Comment: @Cody Yes you can use using directives. However we dont use them for our own code class files. We always prefix a class declaration with its namespace.

Comment: Wow. You don't use using directives? Have you also banned `foreach` loops and maybe comments?

Comment: @Cody...very funny. We are implementing a codebase using strict domain driven design principles. One of these concepts that we try to adhere to is make implicit concepts explicit. We like to explicitly define our own classes prefixed with namespaces...we refactor often and we find this coding standard to be very beneficial. Also, if you have two or more classes with the same name but different namespaces it can be very useful. It really works for us...